# Is it possible to define a constant of a user-defined type in VBA?

Tags: vba, data-structures, constants

I'm relatively new to VBA, and wondered whether it's possible to define a constant that's of a user-defined type? For example;

```
Public Type StdCheckAttribs
    Description As String
    Length As Double
    EndOption As String
End Type

Const CEN56E1_TYPE1_4980_CHECK As StdCheckAttribs = (...instantiation goes here...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you cannot, but why not wrap it in a Function and return default values?

```
Public Function StdCheckAttribsDefault() As StdCheckAttribs
    With StdCheckAttribsDefault
        .Description = "Some value"
        .Length = 100
        .EndOption = "Some value"
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Great minds think alike! After thinking about it, this is the approach I've used! :-)